# Execute deferred trigger only once per row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers, plpgsql

I have a deferred `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on a table, set to fire when a certain column is updated. It's an integer type I'm using as a counter.

I'm not 100% certain but it looks like if I increment that particular column 100 times during a transaction, the trigger is queued up and executed 100 times at the end of the transaction.

I would like the trigger to only be scheduled once per row no matter how many times I've incremented that column.

Can I do that somehow?
Alternatively if triggered triggers must queue up regardless if they are duplicates, can I clear this queue during the first run of the trigger?

Version of Postgres is 9.1. Here's what I got:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER counter_change
    AFTER UPDATE OF "Counter" ON "table"
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE counter_change();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION counter_change()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN

PERFORM some_expensive_procedure(NEW."id");

RETURN NEW;

END;$$;
```

Comment: Your version of Postgres would help. Also the (basic) code of your trigger and trigger function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a tricky problem. But it can be done with [per-column triggers and conditional trigger execution](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) introduced in **PostgreSQL 9.0**.

You need an **"updated" flag per row** for this solution. Use a `boolean` column in the same table for simplicity. But it could be in another table or even a temporary table per transaction.

The expensive payload is executed **once per row** where the counter is updated (once or multiple time).

This should also **perform** well, because ...

- ... it avoids multiple calls of triggers at the root (scales well)
- ... does not change additional rows (minimize table bloat)
- ... does not need expensive exception handling.

Consider the following

### Demo

Tested in PostgreSQL 9.1 with a separate schema `x` as test environment.

#### Tables and dummy rows

```
-- DROP SCHEMA x;
CREATE SCHEMA x;

CREATE TABLE x.tbl (
 id int
,counter int
,trig_exec_count integer  -- for monitoring payload execution.
,updated bool);
```

Insert two rows to demonstrate it works with multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO x.tbl VALUES
 (1, 0, 0, NULL)
,(2, 0, 0, NULL);
```

#### Trigger functions and Triggers

1.) Execute expensive payload

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.trg_upaft_counter_change_1()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

 -- PERFORM some_expensive_procedure(NEW.id);
 -- Update trig_exec_count to count execution of expensive payload.
 -- Could be in another table, for simplicity, I use the same:

UPDATE x.tbl t
SET    trig_exec_count = trig_exec_count + 1
WHERE  t.id = NEW.id;

RETURN NULL;  -- RETURN value of AFTER trigger is ignored anyway

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

2.) Flag row as updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.trg_upaft_counter_change_2()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

UPDATE x.tbl
SET    updated = TRUE
WHERE  id = NEW.id;
RETURN NULL;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

3.) Reset "updated" flag.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.trg_upaft_counter_change_3()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

UPDATE x.tbl
SET    updated = NULL
WHERE  id = NEW.id;
RETURN NULL;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger names are relevant! Called for the same event they are executed in alphabetical order.

1.) Payload, only if not "updated" yet:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER upaft_counter_change_1
    AFTER UPDATE OF counter ON x.tbl
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.updated IS NULL)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE x.trg_upaft_counter_change_1();
```

2.) Flag row as updated, only if not "updated" yet:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upaft_counter_change_2   -- not deferred!
    AFTER UPDATE OF counter ON x.tbl
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.updated IS NULL)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE x.trg_upaft_counter_change_2();
```

3.) Reset Flag. No endless loop because of trigger condition.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER upaft_counter_change_3
    AFTER UPDATE OF updated ON x.tbl
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.updated)                 --
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE x.trg_upaft_counter_change_3();
```

### Test

Run `UPDATE` & `SELECT` separately to see the deferred effect. If executed together (in one transaction) the SELECT will show the new `tbl.counter` but the old `tbl2.trig_exec_count`.

```
UPDATE x.tbl SET counter = counter + 1;

SELECT * FROM x.tbl;
```

Now, update the counter multiple times (in one transaction). The payload will only be executed once. **Voilá!**

```
UPDATE x.tbl SET counter = counter + 1;
UPDATE x.tbl SET counter = counter + 1;
UPDATE x.tbl SET counter = counter + 1;
UPDATE x.tbl SET counter = counter + 1;
UPDATE x.tbl SET counter = counter + 1;

SELECT * FROM x.tbl;
```

Comment: A bit late to the party I know, but is it possible to execute the payload-function only once and *last* (as in only for the last UPDATE stmt)?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of a way to collapse trigger execution to once per (updated) row per transaction, but you can emulate this with a TEMPORARY ON COMMIT DROP table which tracks those modified rows and performs your expensive operation only once per row per tx:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION counter_change() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  -- If we're the first invocation of this trigger in this tx,
  -- make our scratch table.  Create unique index separately to
  -- suppress avoid NOTICEs without fiddling with log_min_messages
  BEGIN
    CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_counter_tx_once
      ("id" AS_APPROPRIATE NOT NULL)
      ON COMMIT DROP;
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tbl_counter_tx_once AS ("id");
  EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table THEN
    NULL;
  END;

  -- If we're the first invocation in this tx *for this row*,
  -- then do our expensive operation.
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_counter_tx_once ("id") VALUES (NEW."id");
    PERFORM SOME_EXPENSIVE_OPERATION_HERE(NEW."id");
  EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    NULL;
  END;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There's of course a risk of name collision with that temporary table, so choose judiciously.

Comment: Exception handling is expensive and not needed. Consider [`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) (new in 9.1) and `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ..) THEN ...; INSERT INTO tbl ..; END IF;`. Also `LOCAL`is just a noise word in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Re: non-exception based handling, yes, there's more than one way to do it.  (Indeed my first tested solution was CREATE IF NOT EXISTS.)  Re: LOCAL, yes, I know, and here I think it reinforces the purpose of using this table.

Comment: +1 Aside from that your solution deserves an upvote, too. Advanced stuff. You could include the current transaction ID with [`txid_current()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT) in the name of the temporary table. Would force you to use dynamic SQL with EXECUTE, though. **OR**, better yet, add a column `xid` to the temp table with a stable name, then you can avoid the problem with static SQL!

Comment: This seems kind of heavy with the new tables, indexes and exception handling, currently I'm at 200 transactions a second and climbing. Also I need it to run after all the work in the transaction is complete, not after the first insert on that particular table. Good technique to know though, thanks.

Comment: Re: *"seems kind of heavy,"* it may be, though I'd suggest profiling.  Re: *"I need it to run after ... the transaction,"* that's handled by the DEFERRABLEness of your trigger CONSTRAINT definition, not by the definition of the function to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done ordinarily, you need some trick to do it.

For example, consider a `balances(account_id, balance)` table containing balances such that you don't want any balance to go negative *at the end* of a transaction, but it can go negative *during* a transaction due to eg. partial updates to the table.

If you do an ordinary `balance >= 0` check, it cannot be deferred and will not work. If you create a deferred constraint trigger and check for `new.balance >= 0`, it will not work either, because the value for `new` is fixed at the time the trigger is scheduled, not when it is executed.

Hence, a potential solution is to actually *query the table in the trigger function*:

```
create function check_balance_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    -- This queries the table at the time the trigger is executed:
    select * from balances into new where account_id = new.account_id;
    if new.balance < 0 then
        raise 'Balance cannot be negative: %, %', new.account_id, new.balance;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create constraint trigger check_balance
after insert or update on balances deferrable initially deferred
for each row execute function check_balance_trigger();
```