# How can I optimize this: Many Postgres triggers calling the same function within a transaction

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a cached field in one of my database tables that get's updated based on many different tables and the state of fields in those tables.

Each of those tables calls the same function via a trigger:  updateCachedField(basetable_id INTEGER).  The updateCachedField function queries all these other tables and calculates the new cached value for the base table.  The updateCachedField function is complicated and very cost heavy.

During a single transaction it's possible for many of the tables that affect the cached field to be changed.  So during a single transaction, the updateCachedField function may get called 50 times... but with only 5 different basetable_id's.

Is there a way to optimize this so that the updateCachedField function only gets called 5 times instead of the 50+?

Comment: Does this other answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937203/execute-deferred-trigger-only-once-per-row-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use a deferrable constraint trigger and query based on the xmin value or other information.  You could in fact also copy "log" data for snapshotting somewhere else.

Without clear information its not really clear what you are looking at but one option is to essentially have three sets of tables:

1. Live tables.  Updates (deltas or other aggregate-useful info) get written to log tables on update or insert.
2. Log tables.  These are append only.
3. Aggregate snapshot tables which periodically aggregate new sets of log tables.

You could then have a live view which would show current aggregate data, aggregating only from the last snapshot.