# postgresql | Disable cascading triggers in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, cascade

I've got a "before insert" and a "before update" triggers. The "before update" trigger does an insert on the same table that launches the "before insert" trigger that i don't need it this time.

I tried disabling the "before insert" trigger and enabling it again after doing the insert but it says that it can't be done because the table is being used...

Regards,
Aitor

Comment: Please post some code here, i think you have to optimize you trigger definition

Comment: i solved it by modifying the insert trigger and asking for the value of a field that is always diferent when both triggers are launched. If the value of the field is null i execute the code of the insert trigger, if not i just get out of the trigger.

Comment: That what i was thinking of, adding a column that indicate even the row is inserted/updated using the trigger or not...

Comment: [This related answer may be of help in similar cases.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937203/execute-deferred-trigger-only-once-per-row-in-postgresql/8954058#8954058)